# Regex must be in length range and contain letters and numbers

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I want to write a regex that will find substrings of length 10-15 where all characters are `[A-Z0-9]` **and it must contain at least 1 letter and one number** (spaces are ok but not other special characters). Some examples:

- `ABABABABAB12345` should match
- `ABAB1234ABA32` should match
- `ABA  BA BABAB12345` should match
- `1234567890987` should not match
- `ABCDEFGHIJK` should not match
- `ABABAB%ABAB12?345` should not match

So far the best two candidates I have come up with are:

1. `(?![A-Z]{10,15}|[0-9]{10,15})[0-9A-Z]{10,15}` - this fails because if the string has 10 consecutive numbers/letters it will not match, even though the 15 character string has a mix (e.g `ABABABABAB12345`).
2. `(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])([A-Z0-9]+){10,15 }` - this fails because it will match 15 consecutive letters as long as there is a number later in the string (even though it is outside the match) and vice versa (e.g. `123456789098765 abcde` will match `123456789098765`).

(I need to do this in python and js)

Comment: so must contain at least one number and one letter?

Comment: `ABCDEFGHIJK` matches the requirements, why do you say it should not match? Same with `1234567890987`

Comment: Are the strings you're looking for contained by themselves on a line?  Or would you want to look for `ABABABABAB12345` in a sentence like `The quick brown fox jumped over the ABABABABAB12345 dog`?

Comment: As stated it would appear you simply want `^[A-Z0-9 ]{15,20}$` but I'm guessing you have additional unstated requirements. Kindly answer the questions in the comments above (by editing). Instead of "...where all characters are [A-Z0-9] (spaces are ok but not other special characters)." just say "where all characters are `[A-Z0-9 ]`" (or "where all permitted characters are in the character class `[A-Z0-9 ]`").

Comment: Sorry! question written at the end of a very long day - missed the really key point that yes, it must contain at least 1 letter and 1 number

Answer (score 1):

If each string is on its own line, then you can use start/end anchors to construct the regex:

- `^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?:\s*[A-Z0-9]\s*){10,15}$`

  - `^` - start of line

    - `(?=.*[0-9])` - lookahead, must contain a number
    - `(?=.*[A-Z])` - lookahead, must contain a letter
    - `(?:` - start a non-capturing group

      - `\s*[A-Z0-9]\s*` Contains a letter or number with optional whitespaace
    - `)` - end non-capturing group
    - `{10,15}` - Pattern occurs 10 to 15 times
  - `$` - end of line

See a live example here: https://regex101.com/r/eWX2Qo/1

Comment: Each string isn't on it's own line - to be clear, each of the examples I want to match above is a substring within a longer string. It might be on it's own line, but it might not.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't account for `ABA  BA BABAB12345`, but this still might help.

Based on what you're trying to match, it looks like you want there to be a mix.

What you can do is two lookaheads.  One looking for a in the following 15 characters, and another looking for a letter in the same space.  If this matches, then it looks for a group of numbers and letters of length 10 to 15.

`(?=.{0,14}\d)(?=.{0,14}[A-Z])[A-Z\d]{10,15}`

https://regex101.com/r/qw1Q0S/1

`(?=.{0,14}\d)`  character 1 through 15 has to be a number

`(?=.{0,14}[A-Z])`  character 1 through 15 has to be a capital letter

`[A-Z\d]{10,15}`  match 10 to 15 letters and numbers if the previous conditions are true

Edit with an [improved answer](https://regex101.com/r/3aGI36/1):

To account for the spaces, you can tweak the above concept.

`(?=(?:. *+){0,14}\d)(?=(?:. *+){0,14}[A-Z])(?:[A-Z\d] *){10,15}`

Above, in the lookahead we were matching `.{0,14}`.  `.` has been changed to `(?:. *+)`, which is a non capturing group that matches `.` in addition to 0 or more spaces.

So putting it together:

Lookahead 1:

`(?=(?:. *+){0,14}\d)`

This matches 0,14 characters that may or may not be followed by spaces.  This effectively ignoring spaces.  This also uses a possessive quantifier ( `*+`) when matching spaces to prevent the engine from backtracking when spaces are matched.  The pattern would work without the `+` modifier, but would more than double the steps taken to match on the example.

Lookahead 2:

`(?=(?:. *+){0,14}[A-Z])`

Same as lookahead 1, but now testing for a capital letter instead of a digit.

If lookahead 1 and lookahead 2 both match, then the engine will be left in a place where our matches can potentially be made.

Actual match:

`(?:[A-Z\d] *){10,15}`

This matches the capital letters and numbers, but now also 0 or more spaces.  The only drawback being that the trailing space will be include in your match, although that's easily handled in post processing.

Edit:

All whitespace (`\r`, `\n`, `\t` and  ) can be [accounted for](https://regex101.com/r/Fiv8JK/1) by using `\s` vs  .

Depending on the amount of space that exists. the possessive quantifier is necessary to prevent catestrophic backtracking.  This modification to the input using [possessive quantifiers](https://regex101.com/r/rCzpIB/1) completes in 22,332 steps, while this one using the same input, but with a regular quantifier, fails match anything due to [catastrophic backtracking](https://regex101.com/r/8YmRmc/1) .

It should be noted that the possessive quantifier `*+` is not supported with javascript or python's builtin re module, but it is supported with python's regex module:

```
>>> import regex
>>> pattern = r'(?=(?:.\s*+){0,14}\d)(?=(?:.\s*+){0,14}[A-Z])(?:[A-Z\d]\s*){10,15}'
>>> regex.search(pattern, 'AAAAAAAAAA\n2')
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 12), match='AAAAAAAAAA\n2'>
>>>
```

Comment: Definitely useful - covers 90% of what I need. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer.  I figured out a way to account for the spaces.

Comment: I get `The preceding token is not quantifiable` errors for the `+`s.

Another edge case I've notice with the initial solution is where there is a line break between 10 and 14 e.g. `AAAAAAAAAA\n2` will match `AAAAAAAAAA`

Comment: Unfortunately javascript doesn't support that feature.  Is python with `regex` (a third party module) an option?

Answer (score 0):

#### Has the right stuff

```
function lfunko() {
  let a = ["ABABABABAB12345","ABAB1234ABA32","ABA  BA BABAB12345","1234567890987","ABCDEFGHIJK","ABABAB%ABAB12?345"];
  let o = a.map((s,i) => {
    let ll = s.split("").filter(s => s.match(/[A-Z]/)).length;
    let ln = s.split("").filter(s => s.match(/[0-9]/)).length;
    let ot = s.split("").filter(s => s.match(/[^A-Z0-9]/)).length;
    let sum = ll + ln
    return (ll > 1 && ln > 1 && sum > 9 && sum < 16 && ot == 0)? `${s} - TRUE`:`${s} - FALSE`;
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(o));

    }
    
Execution log
11:18:20 PM Notice  Execution started
11:18:21 PM Info    ["ABABABABAB12345 - TRUE","ABAB1234ABA32 - TRUE","ABA  BA BABAB12345 - FALSE","1234567890987 - FALSE","ABCDEFGHIJK - FALSE","ABABAB%ABAB12?345 - FALSE"]
11:18:21 PM Notice  Execution completed
```

Your require of [A-Z0-9] does not include spaces so third example should be false.

### Should be

- `ABABABABAB12345` should match
- `ABAB1234ABA32` should match
- `ABA  BA BABAB12345` should not match has spaces
- `1234567890987` should not match
- `ABCDEFGHIJK` should not match
- `ABABAB%ABAB12?345` should not match